# I want to add two functions to a button, but only one function runs

Tags: javascript, html

The two functions work fine separately, but when I try to run them together using onclick in the HTML or AddEventListner or by creating a combined function of the two function, only the calculate function works.

How do I make the genbutton function also work when calculate is clicked?

```js
const generatebutton = document.getElementById("explainbutton");


const wt = document.getElementById("b2");
const ht = document.getElementById("b3");
const bmi = document.getElementById("b5");
 const calc = document.getElementById("b7");
const clr = document.getElementById("b8");

// // calculate bmi funtion
function calculate() {
  console.log(`running calculate`);
  const wt = document.getElementById("b2").value;
  const ht = document.getElementById("b3").value;
  const solve = Number.parseFloat(wt / ht ** 2).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("b5").textContent = solve;
};

// function make explain button appear 

function genbutton () {
  console.log(`running genbutton`);
  generatebutton.style.visibility = "visible";
};

//activate both functions in one click
calc.addEventListener("click", function(){
     calculate();
     genbutton();
});
```

```css
#explainbutton {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-left: 190px;
}
```

```html
<div id="b1">
  <span id="sp1">
    WEIGHT(kg) :
  </span>
  <input type="number" id="b2">
  </input>
</div>
<br>
<div id="b9">
  <span id="sp2">
    HEIGHT(m) :
  </span>
  <input type="number" id="b3">
  </input>
</div>
<br>

<div id="bmibox">
  BMI :
  <span id="b5" </span>
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="What does this mean?" class="styled-button-2" id="explainbutton"> </b>
    

</div>

<br>
<br>
<div id="b6">
  <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Calculate" class="styled-button-2" id="b7">
  <button id="b8">Clear</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Typo.  You forgot to close a `<span` tag, so your markup isn't what you think it is.  (The one just before the button you're trying to show.)

Comment: It runs just fine. I've added console logs to both functions and both trigger, so your problem isn't that the functions don't run, it's that the code inside those functions aren't doing what you think they do, so: time to start debugging. And on a different note: don't set `style` properties, instead add/remove classes using the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property so you can keep your CSS in your CSS files. And if you're not using a linter: start using a linter so your editor can tell you about syntax errors (in your HTML, in this case)

Comment: you dont need to close input tags with </input> although it should work anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS is fine as the comments have said, correct the HTML tags (close the input tags and remove the isolated tags with no pair). Works as needed.

```js
const generatebutton = document.getElementById("explainbutton");


const wt = document.getElementById("b2");
const ht = document.getElementById("b3");
const bmi = document.getElementById("b5");
 const calc = document.getElementById("b7");
const clr = document.getElementById("b8");

// // calculate bmi funtion
function calculate() {
  const wt = document.getElementById("b2").value;
  const ht = document.getElementById("b3").value;
  const solve = Number.parseFloat(wt / ht ** 2).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("b5").textContent = solve;
};

// function make explain button appear 

function genbutton () {
  generatebutton.style.visibility = "visible";
};

//activate both functions in one click
calc.addEventListener("click", function(){
     calculate();
     genbutton();
});
```

```css
#explainbutton {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-left: 190px;
}
```

```html
<div id="b1">
  <span id="sp1">
    WEIGHT(kg) :
  </span>
  <input type="number" id="b2">
  </input>
</div>
<br>
<div id="b9">
  <span id="sp2">
    HEIGHT(m) :
  </span>
  <input type="number" id="b3">
  </input>
</div>
<br>

<div id="bmibox">
  BMI :
  <span id="b5"> </span>
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="What does this mean?" class="styled-button-2" id="explainbutton" /> 
    

</div>

<br>
<br>
<div id="b6">
  <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Calculate" class="styled-button-2" id="b7" />
  <button id="b8">Clear</button>
</div>
```

Comment: [Are "Your code works fine for me" answers acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277923/283366)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277923/are-your-code-works-fine-for-me-answers-acceptable/277958#277958 
I corrected the HTML code and inserted it as an answer, maybe helping the OP find the issue with the HTML.